# SQL Query increment 1 from last row?

Tags: php, sql

since you can't auto increment two columns what would the Query be to get the last row of the table and +1 value of the column to insert a new row.

For example I have a table named `players`

looking abit like this:

```
id    player_id    player_name
 1      15           name1
 2      16           name2
 3      17           name3
```

I'm trying to make an admin panel to create a player from a form, the column 'id' auto increments but I also need player_id to increment too, but id and player_id are not the same as each other.

A query similar to this (I made this up so you can understand a little better)

```
$sql="select top 1 * from `players`  order by id desc";
$result =mysql_query($sql);
while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $playerid=$data['player_id'];
    Insert into `players` (`player_id`,`player_name`) VALUE ('$playerid' + '1', 'name4');

}
```

Comment: oh i see the orange thing below your name :D

Comment: Your database design is not normalized - why do you need both an `id` and a `player_id` in the `players` table?

Comment: sorted, didnt know i could vote answers with my rep

Comment: There is a reason behind it, im using a tpl system with smarty, big source can't remeber why the id is needed but it is.

Comment: That doesn't really clear it up for me - does `player_id` always = `id + 14`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try This Code:

```
    $sql="SELECT player_id FROM `players` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result =mysql_query($sql);
    while ($data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $playerid=$data['player_id']+1;
       }
mysql_query("Insert into `players` (`player_id`,`player_name`) VALUES ('".$playerid."','name4')");
```

Answer (score 3):

The following query will assign the next available `player_id` when inserting.

```
INSERT INTO `players` (`player_id`, `player_name`)
SELECT MAX(`player_id`)+1, 'name4'
FROM `players`;
```

Comment: MAX()+1 This worked for me! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
  $sql="SELECT * FROM `players` ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result =mysql_query($sql);
    $data=mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $playerid=$data['player_id']+1;

mysql_query("Insert into `players` (`player_id`,`player_name`) VALUES ('".$playerid."','name4')");
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, this does insert into players but just gives the player_id value '1', along with this error: Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource

Comment: @user1626410 did you execute the $sql query on table and see what values are you getting??